# error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials) ✖ spec file validation failed

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, bitbucket-pipelines

```
step:
  name: "Deploy to prod environment"
  image: atlassian/default-image:2
  script:
    - source .env
    - envsubst < k8s/deploy.yaml > k8s/deploy-apply.yaml
    - cat k8s/deploy-apply.yaml
    - pipe: atlassian/aws-eks-kubectl-run:2.2.1
      variables:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        CLUSTER_NAME: $CLUSTER_NAME
        KUBECTL_COMMAND: "apply"
        RESOURCE_PATH: "k8s/deploy-apply.yaml"
        DEBUG: "true"
```

I have checked `k8s/deploy-apply.yaml`, when manually applied it runs successfully, after substituting variables that is below command runs successfully:

```
kubectl apply -f k8s/deploy-apply.yaml
```

But while running in bitbucket-pipeline I'm getting the below error:

```
INFO: Successfully updated the kube config.
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
✖ spec file validation failed.
```

I have checked `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` they are valid and have permission.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the IAM user you are referencing here is the one who created the cluster ? this error can occur when you created the cluster with the Root and try to access it with a IAM user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).